Flows: Check if an Opp is an active related target in a Cadence (High Velocity Sales)
In a flow, I need to check if an Opportunity is running in a Cadence.
I'm doing:

Get Record (Opportunity)
Get Record (ActionCadenceTracker): Check if RelatedToId = Opp Id and that State = Running

This does not seem to work as it's returning opps that are not actually in a Cadence now, but they might have been before.
What's the correct way?


Hi there! Welcome to SFSE. Can you please add screenshots of the flow you built as well as the incorrect results that it produced together with the results that you expect. This will enable us to better assist you in your query

What kind of flow is it - record- triggered, scheduled, etc?  What is the main  object - Opportunity?  Please [edit] your post to include these details.
